# Wrong week conversion in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date, time

I have the following date: **2019-11-20** which corresponds to **week 47** of the calendar year. This is also what my excel document says. However, when I do it in Python I get **week 46** instead. I will upload my code but I do not get what's wrong with it. I tried to split up the column I had to date and time separately but still, I get the same problem. Very odd I do not know what's wrong and my local time at my laptop is fine. Thanks for your help in advance!

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime 
import numpy as np
import re

df = pd.read_csv (r'C:\Users\user\document.csv')
df['startedAt'].replace(regex=True,inplace=True,to_replace=r'\+01:00',value=r'')
df['startedAt'].replace(regex=True,inplace=True,to_replace=r'\+02:00',value=r'')
df['startedAt'] = df['startedAt'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S').strftime('%d-%m-%y %H:%M:%S'))


df['endedAt'].replace(regex=True,inplace=True,to_replace=r'\+01:00',value=r'')
df['endedAt'].replace(regex=True,inplace=True,to_replace=r'\+02:00',value=r'')
df['endedAt'] = pd.to_datetime(df['endedAt'], format='%Y-%m-%d')

df['startedAt'] = pd.to_datetime(df['startedAt'])
df['Date_started'] = df['startedAt'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
df['Time_started'] = df['startedAt'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')


df['Date_started'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_started'], errors='coerce')

df['week'] = df['Date_started'].dt.strftime('%U')

print(df)
```

Comment: we cant test this without input data. if i try `pd.to_datetime('2019-11-20').week` it returns 47

Comment: I understand, I thought there was something wrong with the code, I will try to upload a sample, just 5 entries is enough right?

Comment: if it reproduces the error, yes

Comment: I solved it, thanks a lot for your help.